# What is alternatives to use popup to avoid Firefox4 popup maximum count?

Tags: javascript, firefox4

I used to use Firefox3.6 but with Firefox4.0 when certain amount of popoup windows are generated, following message will appear.

`Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs`

According to my research, about:config page has dom.popup_maximum variable to adjust max popup limit but I cannot ask my end users to change their browser setting just because of my app.

I searched alternative coding to popup.
Many of them defines div and hide/show them with CSS using jQuery.

But I have 10 HTML pages with button that popup same page.

window.open("http://www.sample.com","samplePage");

I do not want to pre-define the contents of samplePage in every 10 pages for this reason.

Is there any alternative to popup which I do not have to pre-define in every page?

Comment: I don't see a problem. If the dialogs you're creating are useful to the user then the user won't choose the "Prevent this page..." option and you have no problem (your dialogs will continue to appear and the user can continue to use them). Having the "Prevent" option appear for the user will not interfere with the operation of the dialogs.

Comment: Yes, they have choice to click cancel and display the dialog but that is one extra click and if accidentally they click yes, then the dialog will no longer show up. For usability sake, I cannot do that..

Comment: You can avoid pop–ups by using a suitably styled element placed on top of the document that simulates a pop–up window. However, be aware that one reason for browsers blocking popups is that users find them really annoying so you should find some other way of presenting your content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still do the css trick, but put an iframe in the div.

```
Click button then does the following:
   1. Set iframe src attribute
   2. Show hidden div
```

Comment: I think I will go with using iframe and show modal dialog using jQuery. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can load that sample page dynamically. You either may use frames (especially <iframe>s in here) or any type of ayax, which means receiving data from the server (html, xml, json, whatever) and then showing the data in a <div>. You don't need jQuery for that.

Comment: That is interesting approach.. I will extend my search :)